# Docker контейнер. Как направить трафик из контейнера через eth0:1 вместо eth0:0

Tags: docker

Развернул почтовый сервер в контейнере и заказал на хостинге дополнительный IP под него. 
Теперь на Хост-машине 2 IP адреса. Один для всех остальных контейнеров, другой исключительно для почты.

Все порты при запуске почтового контейнера экспозятся на дополнительный IP и со входящими соединениями проблем нет.
Но исходящие по прежнему используют первый (основной) IP как gateway.
Вопрос:
Как заставить почтовый контейнер стучаться в интернет через дополнительный IP (а не через основной, как все остальные контейнеры).

Спасибо.

Comment: скорее всего, необходимую документацию можно найти по запросу docker configure default bridge